# JSON in CouchDB stange behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, couchdb, seamonkey

I've created updates handler in CouchDB with test code like this(before inserting in Couch I'm removing newlines):

```
function (doc, req) {
    if (req['userCtx']['roles'].indexOf('editor') < 0) {
        return [null, 'Access denied'];
    }
    if (!doc) {
        if (/*!('_id' in req) &&*/ !req['_id'] /*&& 'title' in req['body']*/ && !!req['body']['title'] /*&& 'content' in req['body']*/ && !!req['body']['content']) {
            return [{ 'title': req['body']['title'], 'content': req['body']['content'], 'date': new Date(), 'edited_by': req['userCtx']['name'] }, 'Created' + toJSON(req)];
        }
        return [null, 'Empty' + toJSON({ 'no_id': !req['_id'], 'title': !!req['body']['title'], 'content': !!req.body['\"content\"'], 'body':req.body })];
    }
    doc['date'] = new Date();
    doc['edited_by'] = req['userCtx']['name'];
    return [doc, 'Edited' + toJSON(doc)];
}
```

Angular sends data in POST call

```
{"title":"test","content":"test"}
```

In return I'm getting

```
Empty{"no_id":true,"title":false,"content":false,"body":"{\"title\":\"test\",\"content\":\"test\"}"}
```

What's wrong? Why it don't want to see received object not in direct `a.b`, not in hash `a['b']`, not in even escaped `a['\"b\"']`? I'm hoping that's my fault, not couch's. How to do it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the body to JSON first...

Use body-parser as described here: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/expressjs-4-0-new-features-and-upgrading-from-3-0

Comment: You mean JSON.parse?

Comment: Am I understanding you correct, that "body" stored as plain text?

Comment: Thank thou, that worked. I've lost on this more than two weeks.